# ffmpeg concat demuxer framerate changes from constant to variable

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Issue:

The videos I want to join without re-encoding have a constant framerate of 29.97 and the same encoding settings, however ffmpeg concat changes the final output's  framerate mode to variable. I need it to stay at a constant framerate.

MediaInfo before concat:

```
Frame rate mode             : Constant
Frame rate                  : 29.970 fps
```

MediaInfo after concat:

```
Frame rate mode             : Variable
Frame rate                  : 29.970 fps
Minimum frame rate          : 25.489 fps
Maximum frame rate          : 29.970 fps
```

Original video encoding method:

```
ffmpeg -i whatever.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 18 -r ntsc -an 1.mp4
```

Concat:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i files.txt -c:v copy -movflags +faststart -an output.mp4 -y
```

files.txt (same file for testing)

```
file '1.mp4'
file '1.mp4'
```

Result:

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --e
onv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-lib
nable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libo
inger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --e
--enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --en
b
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 048d34e0] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
Input #0, concat, from 'files.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 601 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1600x900, 473 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 127 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[mp4 @ 0565d420] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1600x900, q=2-31, 473 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tb
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 048d34e0] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mp4 @ 0565d420] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
frame=20668 fps=14443 q=-1.0 Lsize=   40102kB time=00:11:29.57 bitrate= 476.4kbits/s
video:39861kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.605159%
```

ffprobe 1.mp4

```
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=h264
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
profile=High
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1001/60000
codec_tag_string=avc1
codec_tag=0x31637661
width=1600
height=900
coded_width=1600
coded_height=900
has_b_frames=2
sample_aspect_ratio=0:1
display_aspect_ratio=0:1
pix_fmt=yuv420p
level=40
color_range=N/A
color_space=unknown
color_transfer=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
chroma_location=left
timecode=N/A
refs=1
is_avc=true
nal_length_size=4
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=30000/1001
avg_frame_rate=30000/1001
time_base=1/30000
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=10344334
duration=344.811133
bit_rate=473469
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=8
nb_frames=10334
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
TAG:language=und
TAG:handler_name=VideoHandler
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=aac
codec_long_name=AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)
profile=LC
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/44100
codec_tag_string=mp4a
codec_tag=0x6134706d
sample_fmt=fltp
sample_rate=44100
channels=1
channel_layout=mono
bits_per_sample=0
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/44100
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=15206400
duration=344.816327
bit_rate=127983
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=14848
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
TAG:language=und
TAG:handler_name=SoundHandler
[/STREAM]
[FORMAT]
filename=1.mp4
nb_streams=2
nb_programs=0
format_name=mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2
format_long_name=QuickTime / MOV
start_time=0.000000
duration=344.817000
size=26298036
bit_rate=610133
probe_score=100
TAG:major_brand=isom
TAG:minor_version=512
TAG:compatible_brands=isomiso2avc1mp41
TAG:encoder=Lavf57.37.101
[/FORMAT]
```

ffprobe output.mp4

```
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=h264
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
profile=High
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=143727/8615000
codec_tag_string=avc1
codec_tag=0x31637661
width=1600
height=900
coded_width=1600
coded_height=900
has_b_frames=2
sample_aspect_ratio=0:1
display_aspect_ratio=0:1
pix_fmt=yuv420p
level=40
color_range=N/A
color_space=unknown
color_transfer=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
chroma_location=left
timecode=N/A
refs=1
is_avc=true
nal_length_size=4
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=30000/1001
avg_frame_rate=4307500/143727
time_base=1/30000
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=20696688
duration=689.889600
bit_rate=478696
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=8
nb_frames=20676
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
TAG:language=und
TAG:handler_name=VideoHandler
[/STREAM]
[FORMAT]
filename=output.mp4
nb_streams=1
nb_programs=0
format_name=mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2
format_long_name=QuickTime / MOV
start_time=0.000000
duration=689.890000
size=41527343
bit_rate=481553
probe_score=100
TAG:major_brand=isom
TAG:minor_version=512
TAG:compatible_brands=isomiso2avc1mp41
TAG:encoder=Lavf56.40.101
[/FORMAT]
```

Comment: Works fine here with recent nightly build. Post the full ffprobe for whatever, 1 and output.

Comment: added ffprobe output. whatever.mp4 is the same as 1.mp4. using the latest windows binary

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I finally found a workaround.

If you use concat **protocol** everything is ok, the error is only related to concat **demuxer**.